# R create a column by selecting partial strings

Tags: r, regex, bioinformatics, dplyr

I have a data frame and I want to extract the specific string on one of the columns by delimiter but there are several conditions. I want to mutate a new column that contain the COSVxxxx strings only.

#### df:

```
ID
.
COSV50419740
.
.
.
rs375210814
.
rs114284775;COSV60321424
.
.
.
rs67376798;88974
rs1169783812
rs56386506;51676;COSV66451617
rs80358907;52202
.
.
.
482972
629301
COSV66463357
rs80358408;51066
rs80358420;51100;COSV66464432
```

#### desired df:

```
ID  COSV.ID
.   .
COSV50419740    COSV50419740
.   .
.   .
.   .
rs375210814 rs375210814
.   .
rs114284775;COSV60321424    COSV60321424
.   
.   
.   
rs67376798;88974    rs67376798;88974
rs1169783812    rs1169783812
rs56386506;51676;COSV66451617   COSV66451617
rs80358907;52202    rs80358907;52202
.   .
.   .
.   .
482972  482972
629301  629301
COSV66463357    COSV66463357
rs80358408;51066    rs80358408;51066
rs80358420;51100;COSV66464432   COSV66464432
```

I want to keep the string if there are no COSV annotation. However, my problem is that there are some rows containing from one to four annotation by colon delimiter. I tried to use cSplit function to separate them but have no idea how to convert the COSV string into one column.

Comment: Could there ever be _more_ than one `COSV` value in the original column?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen currently, there haven't been more than one COSV value. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sub` here, e.g.

```
df$ID_new <- ifelse(grepl("\\bCOSV\\d+\\b", df$ID),
                    sub("^.*\\b(COSV\\d+)\\b.*$", "\\1", df$ID),
                    NA)
```

This option will assign the (last) COSV value, should it exist in the `ID` column, otherwise it will assign `NA`.